# Quaternion to Yaw pitch roll

Tags: python-3.x, quaternions

I am trying to convert a quaternion to yaw pitch roll euler angles. I am experiencing problems with the gimbal lock. The first strange thing that occurs is that errors already start to appear when the pitch angle is in the neighbourhood of +-pi/2. I thought problems should only occur at exactly pi/2.

Secondly my code shows an incorrect yaw angle of 180 degrees at a pitch of -90 degrees.

I tried the code at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50157131/quaternion-rotation-to-pitch-roll-yaw) and from [this site](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/quaternionToEuler/) but none of them worked. I also tried the [pyquaternion](http://kieranwynn.github.io/pyquaternion/) library, but this one does not even attempt to compensate for gimbal lock. In the end I made the python equivalent of this section of a handbook.

[image]
This worked the best but still gives the above issues. It seems like a problem that must have been solved a 1000 times but I can't pinpoint the issue.

For the quaternion: [ 0.86169383  0.02081877 -0.5058515   0.03412598] the code returns the correct yaw pitch roll angles: [0.15911653941132517, -60.832556785346696, -9.335093630495875]

For the quaternion: [ 0.81154224  0.01913839 -0.58165337  0.05207959] the code returns the incorrect yaw pitch roll angles: [-173.53260107524108, -71.09657335881491, 0.0]

Here is my code:

```
    def yaw_pitch_roll(self):
    """Get the equivalent yaw-pitch-roll angles aka. intrinsic Tait-Bryan angles following the z-y'-x'' convention

    Returns:
        yaw:    rotation angle around the z-axis in radians, in the range `[-pi, pi]`
        pitch:  rotation angle around the y'-axis in radians, in the range `[-pi/2, pi/2]`
        roll:   rotation angle around the x''-axis in radians, in the range `[-pi, pi]` 

    The resulting rotation_matrix would be R = R_x(roll) R_y(pitch) R_z(yaw)

    Note: 
        This feature only makes sense when referring to a unit quaternion. Calling this method will implicitly normalise the Quaternion object to a unit quaternion if it is not already one.
    """
    self._normalise()
    qw = self.q[0]
    qx = self.q[1]
    qy = self.q[2]
    qz = self.q[3]


    print(2*(qx*qz-qw*qy), self.q)
    if 2*(qx*qz-qw*qy)>=0.94: #Preventing gimbal lock for north pole
        yaw = np.arctan2(qx*qy-qw*qz,qx*qz+qw*qy)
        roll = 0
    elif 2*(qx*qz-qw*qy)<=-0.94: #Preventing gimbal lock for south pole
        yaw = -np.arctan2(qx*qy-qw*qz,qx*qz+qw*qy)
        roll = 0
    else:
        yaw = np.arctan2(qy*qz + qw*qx,
            1/2 - (qx**2 + qy**2))
        roll = np.arctan2(qx*qy - qw*qz,
            1/2 - (qy**2 + qz**2))
    pitch = np.arcsin(-2*(qx * qz - qw * qy))

    return yaw, pitch, roll
```

Comment: How do you check if result Euler is correct or not ?

Comment: I actually have some sensors that send their orientation in the form of quaternions. These quaternions seem to be correct as the orientation of an avatar on the screen is correct. So I know the real orientation of my sensor (I have it in my hand) and i know the quaternion is correct --> it must be the conversion algorithm that is wrong.

Comment: Comparing Euler Angels per component is not correct.  Comparing quaternions per component can be done if sign of "w" identical.  Comparing per component of rotation matrix is correct

Comment: @minorlogic could you elaborate a little? What do you mean with comparing Euler Angels per component is not correct?

Comment: There is many Euler Angels combination with different component values, representing SAME rotation.

Comment: This is only true in the gimbal lock position isn't it? (assuming you choose one order of euler angles like i have done here z-y-x)

Comment: No , it is not related to gimbal lock. Just compare rotations as rotation matrix (per 3x3 components) to validate your assumptions

Comment: I can't do that I really need the yaw pitch roll angles. My output needs to be these angles. I don't want to perform a transformation I need to know the angles

Answer (score 1):

Having given a Quaternion q, you can calculate roll, pitch and yaw like this:

```
yaw = atan2(2.0*(qy*qz + qw*qx), qw*qw - qx*qx - qy*qy + qz*qz);
pitch = asin(-2.0*(qx*qz - qw*qy));
roll = atan2(2.0*(qx*qy + qw*qz), qw*qw + qx*qx - qy*qy - qz*qz);
```

This should fit for intrinsic tait-bryan rotation of xyz-order. For other rotation orders, extrinsic and proper-euler rotations other conversions have to be used.

This works well for me in Autodesk Maya, where other solutions with pole exceptions had strange gimbal effects.

Comment: Sorry, I'm working on a completely different topic by now and can't say whether your answer is correct or not. If other people in the comments say that your answer is correct I'll mark it as correct. Thanks for answering!